# Retrieve multiple data from stored procedure using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight and Linq-to-SQL to communicate with the database.

I have a stored procedure which receives 2 parameters (`PFOID` and `Quantity`) and `Userid` and returns a product name.

If we send multiple values like multiple `pfoid`'s and `quantity`'s it will return multiple product names shown as below

The stored procedure looks like this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PFO].[PFOValidateUpdateData]
    @PfoIDs xml, -- list of PFO ID's
    @UserID uniqueidentifier --The Identity of the User making the call.
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET DEFAULT BEHAVIOR
    SET NOCOUNT ON          -- Performance: stops rows affected messages
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW   -- This SP to be the Deadlock victim

    -- Initialise Lock-Timeout and Deadlock vars for Insert
    DECLARE @iLockTimeoutRetries as int 
    DECLARE @iDeadLockRetries as int
    DECLARE @dtLockTimeoutSleepInterval as datetime 
    DECLARE @dtDeadlockSleepInterval as datetime
    DECLARE @iErrorNumber as int

    SET @iLockTimeoutRetries = 0 
    SET @iDeadLockRetries = 0 
    SET @dtLockTimeoutSleepInterval = sCommon.fnLockTimeoutSleepInterval()
    SET @dtDeadlockSleepInterval= sCommon.fnDeadlockSleepInterval()
    SET @iErrorNumber = 0

    -- procedure specific
    DECLARE @idoc as int
    DECLARE @IsBrightstarUser as bit

    RETRY:
    BEGIN TRY
        --Create Temp table to store stores!
        CREATE TABLE [#PFOList]
        (
            [PFOId] nvarchar(50),
            [Quantity] INT
        )

        --Create Temp table to store User stores!
        CREATE TABLE [#UserStoreList]
        (
            [StoreID_XRef]      nvarchar(50)
        )

       print CONVERT(varchar(1000), @PfoIDs)

        --Create Document
        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @PfoIDs

        -- Append to new list of Store records
        INSERT INTO [#PFOList] (
                    [PFOId],
                    [Quantity]
                    )
        SELECT  [PFOID],[Quantity]
        FROM OPENXML (@idoc, 'ArrayOfString/string',2)
        WITH( [PFOID] nvarchar(50),[Quantity] [INT]) Stores
        --WHERE [PFOId] Is Not NULL

        -- Clean UP
        exec sp_xml_removedocument @iDoc

        -- are we dealing with a brightstar user?
        SET @IsBrightstarUser = CASE WHEN exists
            (SELECT *
            FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles AS uir inner join
            dbo.aspnet_Roles  AS roles ON uir.RoleId = roles.roleid
            WHERE roles.rolename = 'Brightstar Employee' and uir.userid = @userid)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

         --Get User Storelist
         INSERT INTO [#UserStoreList] (
                    [StoreID_XRef]
                    )
         SELECT s.StoreId_XRef  
         FROM  PFO.UserStoreLink us(nolock)
         INNER JOIN PFO.Store  s(nolock)
         ON us.StoreId=s.StoreId
         where UserId=@UserID        

         --Select * from [#PFOList]
         --SELECT @IsBrightstarUser AS ISBrightstaruser
         --SELECT * from [#UserStoreList]

    --If BrightstarCustomer Update all the Quantities.
    IF @IsBrightstarUser=1
    BEGIN
               UPDATE 
                    PFO.PFO
                SET
                     IsBrightstarReviewComplete = 1
                    ,[ModifyingUsersID] = @UserID
                    ,[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
                    ,[PlannedQty] = pfol.[Quantity]
                    ,[BrightstarReviewedQty]=pfol.[Quantity]
                FROM
                    PFO.PFO as pfo
                    INNER JOIN [#UserStoreList] as stores on pfo.StoreId_XRef=stores.StoreID_XRef           
                    INNER JOIN [#PFOList] as pfol on pfo.PFOId =  pfol.PFOId 
                WHERE @IsBrightstarUser = 1     
    END
    ELSE BEGIN    
           --Update Non Contrained Orders
           UPDATE 
                PFO.PFO
            SET
                 [ModifyingUsersID] = @UserID
                ,[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
                ,[PlannedQty] = pfol.[Quantity]
            FROM
                PFO.PFO (nolock) as pfo
                INNER JOIN [#UserStoreList] as stores on pfo.StoreId_XRef=stores.StoreID_XRef           
                INNER JOIN [#PFOList] as pfol on pfo.PFOId =  pfol.PFOId 
            WHERE pfo.IsBrightstarReviewComplete=1  AND IsConstraint=0

           --SELECT * from PFO.PFO (nolock) where PFOId='04676723-2afb-49ff-9fa1-0131cabb407c'

        --Update Contrained Orders
        --Get Existing quantities for the User
            CREATE TABLE #ExistingProductQuantity
            (
              [PfoID]  nvarchar(100)  
             ,[Product]  nvarchar(255) 
             ,[PlannedQty]  INT 
             ,[BrightstarReviewedQty]  INT    
            )

            CREATE TABLE #CustProductQuantity
            (
              [Product]  nvarchar(255)
             ,[IsUpdatable]  BIT    
            )

            INSERT INTO #ExistingProductQuantity
            ( [PfoID],[Product],[PlannedQty],[BrightstarReviewedQty])
            SELECT PFOId,InventoryId,PlannedQty,BrightstarReviewedQty
            FROM PFO.PFO as pfo
            INNER JOIN [#UserStoreList] as stores on pfo.StoreId_XRef=stores.StoreID_XRef   
            WHERE pfo.IsBrightstarReviewComplete=1 AND IsConstraint=1       

            UPDATE 
            #ExistingProductQuantity
            SET [PlannedQty]=pfol.[Quantity]
            FROM #ExistingProductQuantity eoq
            INNER JOIN [#PFOList] as pfol on eoq.PFOId =  pfol.PFOId 

            INSERT INTO #CustProductQuantity
            (  [Product],[IsUpdatable] )
            SELECT 
            [Product],
            CASE WHEN SUM(PlannedQty)<=SUM(BrightstarReviewedQty) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM #ExistingProductQuantity
            GROUP BY [Product]

            --SELECT * from #ExistingProductQuantity
            --SELECT * from #CustProductQuantity

           --Update the products that can be updatable
            UPDATE 
                PFO.PFO
            SET
                 [ModifyingUsersID] = @UserID
                ,[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
                ,[PlannedQty] = pfol.[Quantity]
            FROM
                PFO.PFO as pfo
                INNER JOIN #UserStoreList as stores on pfo.StoreId_XRef=stores.StoreID_XRef         
                INNER JOIN #PFOList as pfol on pfo.PFOId =  pfol.PFOId 
                INNER JOIN #CustProductQuantity as pr on pr.Product=pfo.InventoryId 
            WHERE pfo.IsBrightstarReviewComplete=1 AND pr.IsUpdatable=1 AND IsConstraint=1

           --Return the products that are not updatabele    
             select  [Product]          
             FROM #CustProductQuantity
             where [IsUpdatable]=0
    END 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Get the ErrorNumber
        Set @iErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()

        --Handle Deadlock situation (Deletes, Inserts & Updates)
        IF @iErrorNumber = 1205  
        BEGIN
            -- If we have not made enough attempts to break the lock
            IF @iDeadLockRetries < sCommon.fnMaxDeadlockRetries()
            BEGIN
                -- Increment the Attempt count
                SET @iDeadLockRetries = @iDeadLockRetries + 1
                -- Pause to allow the deadlock contention to clear
                WAITFOR DELAY @dtDeadlockSleepInterval
                GOTO RETRY
            END
        END

        -- Handle Lock Timeout situation (Deletes, Inserts & Updates)
        IF @iErrorNumber = 1222  
        BEGIN       
            -- If we have not made enough attempts to break the Deadlock
            IF @iLockTimeoutRetries < sCommon.fnMaxLockTimeoutRetries()
            BEGIN
                -- Increment the Attempt count
                SET @iLockTimeoutRetries = @iLockTimeoutRetries + 1
                -- Pause to allow the lock contention to clear
                WAITFOR DELAY @dtLockTimeoutSleepInterval
                GOTO RETRY
            END
        END

        exec Common.RethrowError 
    END CATCH
END
```

The result is as follows..

```
 Product
 6435LVWK-360-CD819E3
 NSCHI535C1097I360-4C 
 NSCHU485C1819I360-0C

 Return Value
 0
```

My Linq-to-SQL connection is like this

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="PFO.PFOValidateUpdateData")]
    public int PFOValidateUpdateData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "PfoIDs", DbType = "Xml")] System.Xml.Linq.XElement pfoIDs, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "UserID", DbType = "UniqueIdentifier")] System.Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), pfoIDs, userID);
        return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

I am trying to retrieve all the data from the stored procedure but the when I debugging it the return value is "o"..

I would be grateful to you if you could help me retrieve all the data returned by the stored procedure... thank you very much...

Comment: God - I didn't even **know** that T-SQL has labels and `GOTO` .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371445/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure returns a collection of nvarchar's, then the signature of your Linq2Sql method is not correct. It should not return an int, but an [ISingleResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433491/dbml-generates-isingleresultobject-from-my-stored-procedure-when-i-want-a-coll).

So the correct signature will be:

```
public ISingleResult<string> PFOValidateUpdateData(...)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this....;
    return (ISingleResult<string>)result.ReturnValue;
}

var products = PFOValidateUpdateData(...).ToList();
```

If you want to return the results from multiple SELECT's in your stored procedure, you'll have to use [IMultipleResults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371445/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results).

Comment: well the stored procedure is displays the list of products  Product
 6435LVWK-360-CD819E3
 NSCHI535C1097I360-4C 
 NSCHU485C1819I360-0C

 Return Value
 0 but while calling the stored procedure it is not taking the string values.. it is accepting only int (0)... I tried using the Isingleresult and Imultipleresult but it says pfoid cannot be null..thank you very much.. i ll try again..

Comment: It is quite hard to tell what you've tried exactly. What do you mean by "not taking the string values"? It should not *take* them, but it should *return* them. "Accepting only int(0)"? Where?

But as you state "pfoid cannot be null", this indicates your input xml (pfoids) does not contain the information you think it does.

Comment: If I replace the return type int to IsingleReturn<string> near 
     It is throwing an error that the extension of the method was not found...in the view model the PFOValdiateUpdateData method in web.g.cs file is automatically removed. so it is accepting only int as a return type, is there any way to change the return type
                Context.PFOValidateUpdateData(xmlString.ToString(), WebContext.Current.User.UserID, op => and the error is ..Error 45 does not contain a definition for and no extension method could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It seems like you should alter the signature of the method on another location in your code too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502287/does-not-contain-a-definitionand-no-extension-method-error

Comment: Well the same when using IsingleResult<string>.. throwing an other error...The type 'System.String' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping

Answer (score 0):

Well I know this is not the right way...for time being,its working for me...
I created an other table with two columns one ProductId and ID, I am inserting the values returned by the stored procedure, 
in the designer.cs I am returning the table,

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="PFO.PFOValidateUpdateData")]
        public ISingleResult<PFOValidData> PFOValidateUpdateData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "PfoIDs", DbType = "Xml")] System.Xml.Linq.XElement pfoIDs, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "UserID", DbType = "UniqueIdentifier")] System.Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), pfoIDs, userID);
            return ((ISingleResult<PFOValidData>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

And in the Domainservice

```
List<string> PFOValidateUpdateData(string pfoIds, Guid userID)
        {
           List<string> productIdList = new List<string>();

      // Acquire the int  
               result = this.DataContext.PFOValidateUpdateData(element, userID);


               foreach (var item in result)
               {
                   productIdList.Add(item.ProductID);
               }
 return productIdList;
```

To get the multiple values returned by the stored procedure....

Please let me know if there is a better way to solve this... thank you